# Convert date format in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using the code below in oracle sql but would like to change the format.

```
select TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q') - 1 as  LAST_DAY_OF_LAST_QTR
from dual
```

**Result:**
09/30/2017 12:00:00 AM

How can I change it to be **20170930**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With additional [TO_CHAR](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php):

```
select to_char(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q') - 1, 'yyyymmdd') as  LAST_DAY_OF_LAST_QTR
from dual
```